# How to rename files, as they are copied to a datalake from blob storage, with adf

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am performing copy activity from blob Storage to Gen2 datalake store. The normal copy activity copies everything without extension. I want those filenames to be renamed with "filename.extension". How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the file type are you copying?

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of the sink?

Comment: Hi @PUser, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: @JosephXu HI, Thanks for the answer and sry for delay, although i have binary i.e. source and sink. I tried your method and far as i remember it didn't allow me to change the names. Just for the sake of doing fast i used powershell. Its working but its an extra step. haven't  found a solution with data factory yet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can rename those filenames during the copy activity. But we need use a GetMetadata activity and a ForEach activity and inside the ForEach activity we perform copy activity.

Here is what I did to achieve this.

1. First, we can use `Child items` at the GetMetadata activity to get the source files list.
   [image]
2. At the ForEach activity, we can use `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to foreach the source files list.
   [image]
3. Inside the ForEach activity, we can set a Copy activity and use expression `@item().name` to get one file from the source files list.
   [image]
4. Then in the sink dataset, click **Open**:
   [image]
   We can add dynamic content here, here I use the expression `@concat('20201110-',item().name)`  to rename the file name.
   [image]
5. After I run debug, we can see the file name has been renamed according to the rule.
   [image]